# pyside second qt gui doesn't show up

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a Qapplication in my python script that gives a logingui to my chat server.
When the login is complete I want to call upon my chat gui. To achieve this I've used the following 
code:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = LoginWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
#login done
form = ChatWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

This worked when I fired it up with an "empty" gui of the chat. So only the necessary things in it for it to boot up. However when I start connecting signals and stuff the second window just doesn't show up anymore. The console prints a statement from the beginning of the init but after that it falls silent and no gui is present.

Does anyone know how I can fix this weird problem? How is switching a form supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login window should be a subclass of [QDialog](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html), so that it can be run separately from the main application. A QDialog has its own event loop, and provides a return code that can be used to check which action was taken by the user.

So, given this, your code would become:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = LoginWindow()
if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
    window = ChatWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
else:
    print('Login cancelled')
```